# Python an open-source list of words by valence or categories for comparison

Tags: python, nlp

I tend to take notes quite regularly and since the great tablet revolution I've been taking them electronically. I've been trying to see if I can find any patterns in the way I take notes. So I've put together a small hack to load the notes and filter out proper nouns and fluff to leave a list of key words I employ.

```
import os
import re

dr = os.listdir('/home/notes')
dr = [i for i in dr if re.search('.*txt$',i)]
ignore = ['A','a','of','the','and','in','at','our','my','you','your','or','to','was','will','because','as','also','is','eg','e.g.','on','for','Not','not']
words = set()
d1 = open('/home/data/en_GB.dic','r')
dic = d1.read().lower()
dic = re.findall('[a-z]{2,}',dic)
sdic = set(dic)
for i in dr:
    a = open(os.path.join('/home/notes',i),'r')
    atmp = a.read()
    atmp = atmp.lower()
    atmp = re.findall('[a-z]{3,}',atmp)
    atmp = set(atmp)
    atmp.intersection_update(sdic)
    atmp.difference_update(set(ignore))
    words.update(atmp)
    a.close()

words = sorted(words)
```

I now have a list of about 15,000 words I regularly use while taking notes. It would be a little unmanageable to sort by hand and I wondered if there was an open-source library of 
`positive-negative-neutral` or `optimistic-pessimistic-indifferent` or other form of word list along any meaning scale that I could run the word list through.

In a perfect scenario I would also be able to run it through some kind of thesarus so I could group the words into meaning clusters to get a high level view of what sense terms I've been employing most.

Does anyone know if there are any such lists out there and if so, how would I go about employing them in Python?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to try http://nltk.org/

Comment: Instead of filtering the `os.listdir` result, try using the `glob` module. Also, check out the `with`-block idiom for handling files, and try making a separate function for the task of "create a set of words from a file".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thanks. I've looked up the with block and it makes more sense to me now. Appreciate your help. Good suggestions all three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a list of words used for sentiment analysis of Twitter at: http://alexdavies.net/twitter-sentiment-analysis/

It includes example Python code for how to use it.

See also: [Sentiment Analysis Dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188706/sentiment-analysis-dictionaries)

Comment: Thanks @PeterCollingridge looking through the sites now.